# Perl script to telnet and re-telnet when target reboots

Tags: linux, perl, telnet

I need to write a Perl script which runs on Windows to constantly monitor a log file under a Linux machine for a pattern by telnet-ing into Linux box. But the problem is, the Linux machine gets rebooted very frequently (by some other script), the Perl script should re-telnet into Linux box whenever its available (ping-able).

To achieve this, should I keep pinging the Linux machine IP and telnet into the machine when it respond to ping? or is there any other way? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I'd imagine that even on MS Windows Net::Telnet can detect if the remote is down.  Please take a look at the docs for that module and get back to us when you've written something

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to just retry your connection in a loop if that is what you really want.

```
my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new( ... )

while (1) {
    if ( $telnet->open(...) ) {
        # do some stuff
    }
    else {
        sleep 1;
    }
}
```